# Missing WEB-INF folder in Maven Java Project

Tags: java, maven, web-inf

> Blockquote

I have created a simple project(skip archetype selection) in Maven.

Maven created `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/test/java` and `src/test/resources` folders.

Maven did not create WEB-INF folder inside the webapps.
I have also added maven-war-plugin.

How to get WEB-INF folder inside webapps? and
then how to get WEB-INF/web.xml file?

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.prjs</groupId>
  <artifactId>tjsp1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <finalName>tjsp1</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  
</project>
```

Comment: In my eyes the most simpelst way use an IDE like Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans and so far. Maybe I'm wrong some archetypes from Maven will it do for you either.

Comment: How about create a pure web application with wizard of Eclipse and then convert this project to maven?

Comment: Please post your pom file here....

Comment: I tried to upload my pom.xml in the 'Add Comment' section but it did not allow me to upload.

Comment: Add it to the question, not a comment.

Comment: I have uploaded my pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this question is::
Springboot MVC is designed mostly in a programmatic approach, and this WEB-INF folder deals with web.xml files and related stuff, that's the main reason there is no predefined folder structure with WEB-INF